# Solve the initial value problem $y''-6y'+13y=0,\;y(0)=y'(0)=1$ using the Laplace transform.

Tags: complex-analysis

Solve the initial value problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
y''-6y'+13y=0 \\
y(0)=y'(0)=1 
\end{cases}
$$
using the Laplace transform.

I cannot figure out how to factor or get around factoring $L(Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the LT gives you
$$13Y+s^2Y-6(sY-y(0))-sy(0)-y'(0)=0.$$
Plugging in the IC's yields
$$13Y+s^2Y-6(sY-1)-s-1=0.$$
Solving for $Y$ gives you
$$
Y(13+s^2-6s)=s+1-6=s-5,
$$
making
$$Y=\frac{s-5}{s^2-6s+13}=\frac{s-5}{s^2-6s+9+4}=\frac{s-5}{(s-3)^2+4}.$$
Computing the inverse LT yields
$$y(t)=[\cos(2t)-\sin(2t)][\cosh(3t)+\sinh(3t)].$$
The inverse LT you're going to have to complete the square on, as the denominator doesn't factor over the reals.

Comment: I think your inverse LT is wrong.

Comment: @xpaul: Not sure why you're saying that. My $y(t)$ satisfies the DE and the IC's. What is wrong about it, and what would you propose instead?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Sorry I made a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: @xpaul: No problem!